# Excel, magnitude of every three rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data with about 6000 rows. It is split as such:

```
0   | 0.01846

1   |-0.04517

2   |1.01471

0   |0.01846

1   |-0.04745

2   |1.00769

0   |0.03006

1   |-0.04745

2   |1.00922

0   |0.03326
.
.
.
```

Basically the 0,1,2 pattern repeats till the end. Lets call the right side values axis0, axis1, axis2..... Is it possible to plug in the values of axis0,axis1,axis2 into a repeating equation of sqrt(axis0^2+axis1^2+axis2^2) all the way down?

Comment: Can  you show us your expected output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C1: =IF(A1=0,SQRT(SUMSQ(B1:B3)),"")
```

Copy/Paste along column `C` will make the result appear on the beginning of each triplet.